# finding sum of roots of equation

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, substitution, quartics

The sum of all the real number $x$ such that 
$5x^4 - 10x^3 + 10x^2 - 5x - 11=0$, without aid of Calculus is there any way I tried to find one root inspection but was not getting anywhere, and tried recombining to get a solvable equation. Any feasible approach.

Comment: The answer is 2, $\frac{-b}{a}$, if all roots are real.

Comment: "Real roots" i want to know that include imaginary too and plotting it gives two real roots only

Comment: @AshPd Your question specifically asks sum of all **real numbers**.

Comment: @SahibaArora Do you mean all *real roots*?

Comment: @MCCCS I mean all "real numbers such that $\cdots$". I was merely pointing out that in the comments OP says "I want to know that include imaginary too $\cdots$".

Comment: @AshPd Which one is the tough part? Do you finally want sum of all real roots or the the sum of all roots? Please be clear.

Comment: Sum of real roots

Comment: Use the substitution $y = x^2-x$

Answer (score 5):

Note that\begin{align*}5x^4-10x^3+10x^2-5x-11&=5\left(x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x-\frac{11}5\right)\\&=5\left(\left(x^2-x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac{49}{20}\right)\\&=5\left(x^2-x+\frac12-\frac7{2\sqrt5}\right)\left(x^2-x+\frac12+\frac7{2\sqrt5}\right).\end{align*}The equation $x^2-x+\frac12-\frac7{2\sqrt5}=0$ has two real roots, whereas the equation $x^2-x+\frac12+\frac7{2\sqrt5}=0$ has none. So, the sum of the real roots of your polynomial is the some of the real roots of the polynomial $x^2-x+\frac12-\frac7{2\sqrt5}$, which is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite our equation in the following form.
$$x^5+(1-x)^5=12.$$
Now, let $1-x=y$.

Thus, we need to solve $$x^5+y^5=12$$ or
$$x^4+y^4+x^2y^2-xy(x^2+y^2)=12$$ or
$$x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-x^2y^2-xy(1-2xy)=12$$ or
$$(x^2+y^2+xy)(x^2+y^2-xy)-xy(1-2xy)=12$$ or
$$(1-xy)(1-3xy)-xy(1-2xy)=12$$ or
$$5x^2y^2-5xy-11=0,$$
which gives $$xy=\frac{5-\sqrt{245}}{10}$$ because $$xy\leq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Thus, we need to solve
$$x^2-x-\frac{7\sqrt{5}-5}{10}=0,$$
which gives two roots:
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{14}{\sqrt{5}}-1}}{2}$$ and
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{14}{\sqrt{5}}-1}}{2}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an equation like this
$$P (x) = (x - a) (x - b) (x - c) (x - d)=0$$
then $a,b,c,d$ are the solutions. Thus expanding polynomial $P(x)$ we get
$$x^4 -(a+b+c+d)+x^2 (a b+a c+a d+b c+b d+c d)-x (a b c+a b d+a c d+b c d)+a b c d=0$$
therefore the sum of the roots of your equation can be easily obtained dividing the equation by the leading coefficient
$$x^4-2 x^3+2 x^2-x-\frac{11}{5}=0$$
the coefficient of the term having degree $n-1$ is the opposite of the sum of the roots, so $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=2$

Hope it is clear

Comment: The term of degree 0 is the product of the roots if the degree of the equation is even, the opposite if the degree is odd

Comment: And how do you use this in order to find the sum of the *real* roots?